# Node Js in Cloud Run and Sqlite stored in Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, sqlite, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

So I wanted to create a simple **Node API** using **Express** and using **Sqlite** as the database.

I wanted to host the Node API in **GCP Cloud Run** but I can't store the sqlite database file. I though of first putting the Node JS Application and Sqlite file in a instance in compute engine.

But then I though since sqlite only needs the sqlite file to run, I could just host the Node Js API in **Cloud Run** and store the sqlite database file in **Cloud Storage** and since the database in not really going to be accessed a lot and have a lot of data. I API is only used **3** people during work hours 9-5 5 days a week for my Client.

I was wondering if this is possible and if this is the cheapest option.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot do that. That's not how DBs work. Sqlite doesn't just 'need' the DB file it needs a proepr filesystem to provide safe and performant read write access.

You can try mounting filestore to cloud run and have sqlite there and that might be the closest to what you want https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-filestore

You are better off having an instance that has the app and sqlite together or write your data to a cloud DB like google's managed DBs, yugabyte, cockroachdb etc

Comment: This is correct - in particular Google Cloud Storage writes have to write the entire file at once, but sqlite is designed to write small sections. So sqlite in GCS would be very inefficient. You will also have dataloss if two cloud run instances overlap read-modify-write loops or a cloud run instance terminates suddenly. Google Cloud SQL has a free tier which will fit your needs well.

Comment: Hi yea I don't think Google Cloud SQL has a free tier because when I was using the lowest end shared core I got a bill for around $40. Do you mean I should use Google Compute Free e2.micro Instance to create a Mysql database in that?

Comment: If cost is a big concern use a $6 DigitalOcean server. Run your node js app and sqlite db there. Mysql on an ec2 micro is like what are you even trying to do at that point.